# Spring 5 Webflux rest controller - How to perform input validation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator, spring-webflux

I'm building a web app having some Rest Controller as :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = Path.ROOT)
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private AService service;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Flux<ItemResponse> doSomething(@RequestBody @Valid final ItemRequest request) {
        return service.pleaseDoSomething(request);
    }


}
```

My input object is like :

```
public Class ItemRequest{
   @NotNull
   private String anInputValue
}
```

My app have the annotation @EnableWebFlux

The problem is that no validation happen at all and when i remove the previous annotation, all works fine.

I'm using Spring boot 2.0.3 / tomcat dep

what's going on ?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244769/how-to-validate-mono-when-using-spring-reactive

Comment: SpringBoot automatically configures and starts a reactive runtime when detected. Adding `@EnableWebFlux` disables parts of that.

Comment: @Jorj thanks but that's not exactly my use case, in your issue, they are trying to validate a reactive object which is not possible because you have to wait to have the whole object before doing any validation

Comment: @M.Deinum true so I need to define a custom WebFluxConfigurer right ? seems I can override a getValidator(). the question is how to get the default validator available in the classpath ?

Comment: Why would you need that? You state that everything works if you remove the `@EnableWebFlux` annotation...

Comment: I'm using thymeleaf and i need to override ressourceHandlers

Comment: @Seb please pay attention to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508618/spring-5-webflux-functional-endpoints-how-to-perform-input-validation/46540102#46540102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [the Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux-auto-configuration), adding `@EnableWebFlux` means that you want to take full control of the WebFlux configuration. This includes web validation in this case.

Now there are several ways to customize resource handling in your application - you can use various `spring.resources.*` configuration keys, or add your own configuration class that implements `WebFluxConfigurer` and override the `addResourceHandlers` method.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @M. Deinum and @Brian Clozel
Here is the custom configuration class I needed to have at the same time thymeleaf and validation working

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebFluxConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Resource
    private ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver thymeleafReactiveViewResolver;

    @Autowired
    private Validator defaultValidator;

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return defaultValidator;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(final ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.viewResolver(thymeleafReactiveViewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .resourceChain(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: there's still the `@EnableWebFlux` annotation on it - and your configuration setup is reflecting was Spring Boot is already doing for you. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: true, what is weird is that when I remove the @EnableWebFlux My WebFluxConfig does not seem to be use :/

Comment: You mean if you put a debug break point in that class it's not being executed? Do you have `spring-boot-starter-web` on the classpath? Maybe Spring Boot is configuring your app as a Spring MVC application?